# I can't use @PostConstruct and @PostDestroy with Java 11

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations

I've got problem with using `@PostConstruct` and`@PostDestroy` annotations in my project. I can't use these annotations and it looks like these doesn't exist despite the fact that I imported Java's annotations. I am using Java 11 and that is content of my `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '5.1.0.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.7'
    compile group: 'javax.annotation', name: 'javax.annotation-api', version: '1.3.2'
    provided group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '4.0.1' 
}
```

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Note that both `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` annotations are part of Java EE. And since Java EE has been deprecated in Java 9 and removed in Java 11 we have to add an additional dependency to use these annotations:

For Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

If using Gradle

```
implementation "javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2"
```

Found here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-postconstruct-predestroy

Comment: For reference, gradle: `implementation "javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2"`

Comment: Is this dependency available for Ivy ?

Comment: Yes, If you look on maven central you can find the proper format for including dependencies for many different package managers https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3.2

Answer (score 2):

You have only spring-webmvc, you need the rest of the spring to be able to use their annotations. Probably spring-core and spring-annotations.

Comment: Thanks! It was the reason of my problem.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense that this is the solution because @PostConstruct is no spring annotation.

Comment: @unwichtich I disagree, it makes perfect sense. Indeed these are javax.annotation, but spring can serve these annotations, and it can be deduced from the context of this question that the OP wanted exactly this behaviour. Yes, I could do a long discussion here with the OP, but maybe He just forgeted that spring is divided and not a single jar?

Comment: Ah ok I overlooked that the OP only imported the API package and that the implementation was missing. You are right!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution which worked for me is this.
Go to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.2
and download the jar file.
Then copy the the jar file to your project lib directory.
Finally point the project build path, under class path to the file you pasted into your local lib folder.