# Using @PostConstruct or @PreDestroy in Java11 module

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-11, java-module

I am implementing a module for Java11 and want to use annotations from JSR250 (javax.annotation.PostConstruct and javax.annotation.PreDestroy).

I already changed the according dependency from:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

to this:

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

That artifact `javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar` contains in `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` this line:

```
Automatic-Module-Name: java.annotation
```

Hence, I tried to add this to my module-info.java file:

```
  requires java.annotation;
```

However, I get an error for this import:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
```

The error message is:

```
The type javax.annotation.PostConstruct is not accessible
```

I already studied the following related questions but am still unable to resolve my issue:

- [I can't use @PostConstruct and @PostDestroy with Java 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52701459/i-cant-use-postconstruct-and-postdestroy-with-java-11)
- [Intellij: how to add java.annotation module for javax.annotation.PostConstruct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52084698/intellij-how-to-add-java-annotation-module-for-javax-annotation-postconstruct) (Please note that I am using Eclipse with JDK11 and that does not contain a module `java.xml.ws.annotation`).

Comment: the error is from Eclipse compiler or Maven?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52913597/springboot-org-hibernate-mappingexception-could-not-get-constructor-for-org-hi

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this issue in Eclipse 2019-06 (4.12). Which version do you use?

Comment: yep, error occurs in Eclipse 2019-06. Are there fixes already available?

Comment: It seems as if the Java module support in Eclipse 2019-06 is rather buggy. So if you have some compile error in your module then you also get wired other phantom errors as a side effect.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred only in Eclipse.
It actually turned out that other unrelated compile errors where causing some side effects in Eclipse. After resolving those and refreshing and cleaning the project the described error magically disappeared.
Special thanks to @howlger and @Naman for pointing me in the right direction.